# Responsive Grids: Zen Grids vs. Suzy

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm about to start a new project and i'm having a hard time choosing between Zen Grids & Susy.
Could you guys tell me what the pros/cons of each framework are?

**For reference**

- http://zengrids.com/
- http://susy.oddbird.net/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Zen Grids, but I have used Susy - I've also never heard Zen Grids come up in the compass google discussion group - but I've heard of Susy plenty of times.

I don't know if that means that Susy is inherently more difficult to use or just because it's more popular.  My tendency is to believe the later to be true - but maybe that is just a bias opinion because I've used Susy for a while now.

Anyways, it's great to have another option - I'm excited to hear other peoples comments who have HAD EXPERIENCE with both comment in here.  I am tempted to start a new project with Zen Grids just to give it a try.

I'm sorry that I don't have a more objective opinion.  My main point is that I know I have heard of Susy - actually a lot - and for a long time.  It is my opinion that Susy is more popular, and therefor I tend to stick to the trending projects.  Who knows, though - this is the web and anything is possible in the world of CSS development these days.  So, may the best grid system win!

Cheers,
-Jeremy

Comment: Susy has been around for over 3 years, while Zen Grids were created last year - which explains the difference in mentions. Other options you might look at include [Salsa](http://tsi.github.com/Salsa/) (which combines the two) and [Singularity](http://singularity.gs/) (which does a few other things), though both of those are being [merged into Susy as we speak](http://oddbird.net/2013/01/01/susy-next/).

Comment: I've been using zen grids for my last two projects and I liked it. It's very simple to use and that may also be a limitation for some people. Susy seems to have more options or features but also looks a bit more complex to get started with compared to zen grids.

Answer (score 0):

for sites that need both LTR and RTL directions, zen-grids are very neat and simple. but in singularity or susy, there is solution, but needs a bit of work.(lots of work for me). I think this is main advantage of zen-grids over susy. and it doesn't come up with lots of versions, and you don't need to deal with deprecated syntax at susyone etc.
but susy has lots of features over zen-grids that I never needed to use them. so the answer is "it depends".